# Number of ways to split a list into consecutive parts

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can a list of size $n$ be split into consecutive sublists? For example, for $n=3$ the answer is 4:
$$
[[[1, 2, 3]], [[1], [2, 3]], [[1, 2], [3]], [[1], [2], [3]]]
$$
In general it is $2^{n-1}$ - why?

Comment: This is simply the number of ways of writing $n$ as an ordered sum of positive integers. Such decompositions of $n$ are called [*compositions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $n$, and the linked article explains the result pretty clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write down the numbers $1$ to $n$; in between each two consecutive integers on the list, you can insert a separator or not.  Each such list with chosen insertions corresponds to one of your lists of consecutive integers.

Example (using $\mid$ as a separator):  $n=5$: The list  $1, 2 \mid 3 \mid 4, 5$ corresponds to $[1,2], [3], [4,5]$.

Since there are two choices (seperator or not) between each pair of consecutive integers, you get your result.

Comment: Of course, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_n$ denote the number of ways a list of size $n$ can be split into consecutive sublists. Observe that for a list of size $n$ there are $n-1$ possible positions where we can insert separators.
$$
\_\ |\ \_\ |\ \_\ |\ \_\ |\ \_\ |\ \_\ 
$$
The number of ways to insert $1$ seperator is $\binom{n-1}{1}$, the number of ways to insert $2$ seperators is $\binom{n-1}{2}$, $\dots$ therefore
$$
T_n = \binom{n-1}{0} + \binom{n-1}{1} + \binom{n-1}{2} + \cdots + \binom{n-1}{n-1} = 2^{n-1}
$$
That is : $T_2=2$,$\ \ T_3=4$,$\ \ T_4=8$,$\ \ \cdots$